# How the three drop down list depends on other (eg 1st depends on 2nd and 2nd depends on 3rd and vise versa

Tags: c#

I have three drop down list and using these drop down it filters and displays data in grid view .It gives proper answer but the problem is that when i select 3rd drop down and after that selecting 2nd it not gives proper data display in grid view (3rd drop down not depends on 2nd)

Comment: If you dont post without the sample code what ever you have tried then the question will be considered as improper and it will be flagged by others to delete the question. To prevent that add the sample code so that others can guide you. Here is the guide how to ask the question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please go through it.

Comment: you are looking for this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-one-dropdownlist-with-other-dropdownlist-in-asp-ne/ the cascading dropdown in asp.net

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question accordingly. Right now we don't have much information to go on. Try adding your UI framework like `WPF`, `ASP` or `WinForms` as tag aswell.